# How can I create a read-only Boolean dependency property that returns `And` operation between two other dependency properties

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

How can I create a custom read-only Boolean dependency property that returns `And` operation between two custom Boolean dependency properties, for example (A, B),

And when A or B changes, I want the result property to trigger.

Any help to achieve that!

Comment: Maybe you just need a multibinding?

Comment: My case is more complex than And operation and two properties (it's just a sample), I think it's better to implement it by a dependent dependency property.

Comment: Okay, I see. Do you define the source DPs yourself?

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, they're custom dependency properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part 1: dependencies.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Source1Property =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Source1",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(UpdateTarget)));

public bool Source1
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(Source1Property); }
    set { SetValue(Source1Property, value); }
}

void UpdateTarget(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyControl self = (MyControl)d;
    d.Target = d.Source1 && d.Source2;
}
```

Part 2: read-only

```
internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey TargetPropertyKey =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
        "Target",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(false));

public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
    TargetPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

public bool Target
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(TargetProperty); }
    protected set { SetValue(TargetPropertyKey, value); }
}
```

Disclaimer: I didn't try the part 2.

Part 3:
if the source dependency properties are not defined by you, you can do the following trick:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
        MyControl.Source1Property,
        typeof(MyControl)));
if (dpd != null)
    dpd.AddValueChanged(this, UpdateTarget);
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I implement it in case that the sources not custom dependency properties ?

Comment: @Homam: yes, for this case you need part 3 instead of part 1 in the answer.

Comment: @Vlad, a very nice answer except that I think you might have made a mistake. Although that code will compile, I think that you should have used the `DependencyPropertyKey` in the setter and not the `DependencyProperty` because that's `readonly` so will throw an `Exception` even if trying to set it locally: `protected set { SetValue(TargetPropertyKey, value); }`

Comment: @Sheridan: thank you, you are right. Just tried it in a test project and corrected the code accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by defining your two dependency properties `A` and `B` (for the sake of the example, I guess), and define a callback to be executed whenever these changes, using [PropertyMetaData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata.aspx) in the [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) constructor. In this callback, simply perform the calculation you want and set the `Result` depdendency property to that value. Here is a working example:

```
public class Data : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(Boolean), typeof(Data), new PropertyMetadata(false,HandleValueChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(Boolean), typeof(Data), new PropertyMetadata(false, HandleValueChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResultProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Result",typeof (Boolean), typeof (Data));

    private static void HandleValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.SetValue(ResultProperty, ((Data)d).Result);
        Debug.WriteLine("Value change");
    }

    public bool Result
    {
        get { return A & B; }
    }

    public bool A
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(AProperty); }
        set
        {
            if ( A != value )
                SetValue(AProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public bool B
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool) GetValue(BProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            if (B != value)
                SetValue(BProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, Thanks, You answered me, but I have to select one as answered